# How do I get a 12th pod?

Tags: streetpass-squad-mii-force

In the pod diagram in *Mii Force* there are 12, not 10 pod slots. Three for each weapon plus 2 more. How do I get the 12th pod given, as far as I know, *StreetPass Mii Plaza* only supports 10 StreetPass tags?

Comment: I just learned today that I can move pods around all I like. I suspect that NPC pods may show up if I get 10 tags, so I will see when I can get that happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten 10 pods via hiring mercenaries, it looks like I can have up to 3 level 3 weapons (full power) and 1 level 1 weapon, or two level 3 weapons and 2 level 2 weapons with 10 Miis. There doesn't seem to be any extra Miis that pop up to give 12 pods.